# SetWindowsHookEx with WM_KEYBOARD refuses to work but does not fail

Tags: winapi

I need to be able to programatically disable keyboard input in an application that my DLL is injected into. Initially I tried hooking the WindowProc but it doesnt work for all applications, now I'm trying to install a keyboard hook using SetWindowsHookEx

This is the code for hooking from the DLL, all functions are static inside a class:
(DLLHandle is the handle saved from DllMain)

```
void SomeClass::HookKeyboard()
{
    KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, HookedKeyboard, DLLHandle, 0);
    if(KeyboardHook == NULL) {
        Logger::Warn("Failed to install low level kbd hook %d", GetLastError());
    }
}

LRESULT SomeClass::HookedKeyboard(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Logger::Info("Keyboard");
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

SetKeyboardHookEx succeeds but callback is never called...

Comment: `WH_KEYBOARD` only works when a hooked thread processes `WM_KEYDOWN`/`UP` window messages.  Does the app you are hooking have an active UI message loop?  Is it even a UI app, or a console app? How are you injecting your DLL into it?

Comment: the app has an UI, injecting it via LoadLibrary with remote thread, if the app isnt processing WM_KEYDOWN/UP messages, do you a foolproof solution for blocking input programmatically ? basically my dll is a game overlay and when i enable it i want to disable any input going into the game

Comment: "*basically my dll is a **game** overlay*" - that would have been useful information to provide up front. Games don't usually use window messages to handle user input, they tend to access input hardware more directly.